# Import common proto in each crate

Tags: rust, protocol-buffers, rust-tonic

I'm using [tonic_build](https://github.com/hyperium/tonic).

I have this dir structure:

```
- Cargo.toml (workspace)
- src
  - common
    - Cargo.toml
    - src
      - common.proto

  - crates
    - players
      - Cargo.toml
      - build.rs
      - src
        - proto
          - players.proto (I would like to import src/common/src/common.proto here)

    - teams
      - Cargo.toml
      - build.rs
      - src
        - proto
          - teams.proto (I would like to import src/common/src/common.proto here)
    
    - others...
```

as you can see I have many crates under `crates` dir and I have a `common.proto` which I would like to import in my crates.

I'm using a `build.rs` for each crate because I cannot (right?) use one for the entire Cargo workspace (I tried: Cargo doesn't start build.rs in workspace root dir).

So I'm trying to import common.proto in file like this:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package players;

import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";

import "src/common/src/common.proto";
```

and in my VSCode this is working.

But when I start `build.rs` throws with:

```
error: failed to run custom build command for `players v0.1.0`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `C:\prj\target\debug\build\orders-b13065cbe3fac50f\build-script-build` (exit code: 1)
  --- stdout
  cargo:rerun-if-changed=src/proto/players.proto
  cargo:rerun-if-changed=src/proto

  --- stderr
  Error: Custom { kind: Other, error: "protoc failed: src/common/src/common.proto: File not found.\r\nplayers.proto:6:1: Import \"src/common/src/common.proto\" was not found or had errors.\r\nplayers.proto:29:3: \"common.Pagination\" is not defined.\r\nplayers.proto:49:9: \"common.Page\" is not defined.\r\n" }
[Finished running. Exit status: 0]
```

My `build.rs` is:

```rust
fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    tonic_build::configure()
        .out_dir("src/proto")
        .compile(
            &["src/proto/players.proto"],
            &["src/proto"],
        )?;

    Ok(())
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: It's confusing but it's necessary to remember that there are effectively two sets interdependencies here. The interdependency of the proto sources and the interdependency (covered by `Cargo.toml`) of the Rust code.

Comment: It may be better (!?) for you to move all your protobuf sources into a single folder (`protos`) and then reflect the proto `package` structure in folders. E.g. `package players` would need to be in the folder (!) `protos/players` etc. Then, when you use `protoc` either directly or indirectly using `tonic_build`, you will want to provide `compile` with a `proto_path` that roots|anchors on `protos` folder as `includes`.

Answer (score 2):

For example:

```
.
├── build.rs
├── Cargo.lock
├── Cargo.toml
├── protos
│   ├── common
│   │   └── common.proto
│   └── teams
│       └── players.proto
├── src
│   └── main.rs
└── target
```

With e.g.:

`players.proto`:

```protobuf
syntax = "proto3";

package players;

import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";
import "common/common.proto";

message Bar {
    google.protobuf.Timestamp timestamp = 1;
    common.Foo foo = 2;
    
}
```

**Note:** The `import` is rooted under `protos` but then follows the folder structure. The folder structure should match the `package` structure. The field reference uses the `package` structure (`{package}.{Message}`).

And:

`build.rs`:

```rust
fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    tonic_build::configure()
        .build_server(false)
        .compile(
            &["protos/common/common.proto","protos/teams/players.proto"],
            &["protos"],
        )?;
    Ok(())
}
```

**Note:** With the exception of `google.protobuf` which is included by default by the `PATH` to `protoc`, we must set the `proto_path` (tonic `includes`) to the root location(s -- each root if these are disjoint) of the `protos`.

Comment: Thank you very much for this alternative way. I kind like it. Just one thing I cannot make root's (workspace) `build.rs ` work. Do you know if it work in a workspace?

Comment: You're welcome! I haven't tried `tonic-build`'s `build.rs` in a workspace. This [issue](https://github.com/hyperium/tonic/issues/484) in `tonic`'s repo suggests that it *should* work.